FileDownload Open in a new tab
I implemented TelerikUpload in my project. Upload is working fine.
My following code is downloading the file to download folder then I have to click it to open the folder. But I want the file to open in a new tab or in a popup window without the download.
I tried all options, Any option I try it is always downloading to download folder.
Is it because my Blazor application is a single page app?
    //JRazor file
<a href="" @onclick="() => AttachmentOpen(item)" @onclick:preventDefault target="_blank">fileName</a>

function openFile(filename, content, mimeType) {
    var blob = new Blob([content], { type: mimeType });
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(anchorElement);    
    anchorElement.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    anchorElement.href = url;
    anchorElement.target = "_blank";
    anchorElement.click();

    anchorElement.remove();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
//Razor.cs file
private async Task AttachmentOpen(Attachment attachment)
{
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(attachment.fileName);
    var mimeType = MimeTypeHelper.GetMimeType(extension);
    byte[] DownloadFileBytes = ReadFile(attachment.Path);
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("openFile", attachment.fileName, FileBytes, mimeType);
}


Perhaps the browser is set to always download the supplied mimeType - or doesn't know how to display whatever that mimeType is- what mimeType are you dealing with?

my allowed mime types are { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif", ".txt"}

Those aren't mime types, those are file extensions

i.e. what is the actual value of mimeType in function openFile

Got it, I updated the mimeTypes, its working as expected. Thanks for your suggestion.
